# Получение имен файлов php без загрузки на сервер

Tags: html

Как получить в input имена всех файлов, загруженных через input multiple?

Без загрузки на сервер, а только получение имен файлов в строке или таблице. Решение с $_FILES не подходит. Так как нет загрузки на сервер.
Интересует решение именно на php. javascript не предлагать. 
Заранее очень благодарен!

Comment: Так как вы __не загружаете__ файлы на сервер, то вы ничего не сможете сделать с помощью php.

Comment: Я вас очень прошу прочесть вот эту статью: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke Из нее станет понятно, что вопрос не имеет смысла. Без загрузки файлов на сервер, их имен на сервере получить невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Присоединяюсь к предыдущим ораторам. Без отправки на сервер PHP ничего не будет знать о том, что происходит на фронте. В качестве одного из решений (если стоит задача именно файлы не отправлять) можно на input повесить событие onChange и опять-же AJAX-запросом слать эту строку на сервер. Но это уже JavaScript. Сами файлы загружаться не будут, но сервер получит их имена.

Comment: По поводу AJAX запроса, допустим есть onChange "onchange="document.getElementById('img_name').value = this.value.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop()"". Он переводит на input имя только одного файла. Как сделать что бы он выводил имена нескольких файлов?

Comment: @HapochkaV https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FileReader